# High voltage power supply polarity for X-ray tube application

Tags: high-voltage, polarity, x-rays

High voltage power supplies (HVPS) in the range 100 to 200 kV are used for working with X-ray tube. Some HVPS produce negative output voltage or even bipolar output including negative and positive voltage. I want to know which type of HVPS is proper for X-ray tube; negative voltage, positive voltage or the bipolar one?

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer.

Comment: There is no right or wrong answer but bipolar reduces the potential difference from ground that you have to deal with.

Comment: Depends on tube type. Bypolar, and negative are usually used... Never positive, due to the want to have a gounded enclosure...

Comment: Why never to use positive voltage supply? 200kV is quite high surge to make the xray tube running.